# Improve UPDATE/DELETE performance SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

We have process in our project where records in a table with specific flag is deleted and remaining record's flag is updated.

Table have approx 45 million records and half the records are with flag='C' and remaining half with flag='P'.

Process run once in a day to delete all the records with flag 'P' and then update all the remaining ones with flag 'C'

Below are the two statements that is run through SSIS package.

```
DELETE FROM dbo.RTL_Valuation WITH (TABLOCK) 
WHERE Valuation_Age_Flag = 'P';

UPDATE dbo.RTL_Valuation WITH (TABLOCK) 
SET Valuation_Age_Flag = 'P' 
WHERE Valuation_Age_Flag = 'C';
```

Currently process takes 60 minutes to complete. Is there any way process time could be improved ?

Thanks

Comment: 1) Clustered index put flag first - may cause perf problems in other areas. 2) Remove unused indexes. 3) why do you want a tablock?

Comment: @Ben Clustered index is defined on identity column which which is RTL_Valuation_UID. Non Clustered index is defined on Valuation_age_flag colmn. There are other indexes as well on other column. 
Remove TABCLOCK should help ?; dint try that option as it was already present from previous designer.

Comment: There may be a reason you need tablock. You have lots of options here, but it is hard to advise what is best without knowing everything about the system.

Comment: @Ben The resultset of the table is Daily PnL calculation of clients contracts. Business run their query on this table for daily reporting purpose. Other than this, table isn't used anywhere in the system. The flag helps them to differentiate current and previous day data.

Comment: If you are using this column to help differentiate data for specific days why not use a date datatype? Seems a lot simpler. You don't have to update the rows that are current for the next day, they just become current because of the value in the date column.

Comment: @Sean Lange there is already another column valuation_date that tells the date at which valuation data was run. But our client wanted this way with valuation_age_flag

Comment: Well that is just plain silly. Sometimes clients demand the stupidest things and we can't protect them from themselves. :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 10000 rows at a time. You are creating one enormous transaction that takes up a lot of room in the transaction log (so it can be rolled back).

```
     set nocount on
      DELETE  top (10000) FROM dbo.RTL_Valuation   WHERE valuation_Age_Flag = 'P';    
    while @@rowcount()>0

    begin
     DELETE  top (10000) FROM dbo.RTL_Valuation   WHERE valuation_Age_Flag = 'P';    
end
```

You can try 1,000, 5,000 or some other number to determine which is the best 'magic' number to quickly delete rows from a large table on your install of SQL Server. But it will be a lot faster that doing a big delete. The same logic applies to the update.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this option today. The data actually grew from 1 million to 45 over a period of 1.5 years.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I assume, that when you perform your delete and update statements it results into two scans of the entire table (one to identify the rows to delete and one to identify the rows to update) and then you have to perform fully logged delete and update operations over it.

There is nice trick for situations like this if your database is in the simple recovery model. However, whether this is suitable for you depends on other circumstances (e.g. how many indexes you table has, whether there are some references, data types ...) that I am not able to asses from your description. It requires more coding but it usually results into much better performance. You would have to test whether it works better for you than your original approach.

Anyway, the trick works like this:

1. Instead of delete and update operations just select the rows you want to keep (including the changes of the flag) using "SELECT INTO" construct into new table. This results in the minimally logged insert operation and single table scan. You can use also the "INSERT INTO SELECT" construct but there you must fulfill some additional conditions to get the minimally logged insert.
2. Once data is in the new table, you have to build all required indexes on it.
3. Once all indexes are build, you just truncate the original table and using the SWITCH command you simply switch the data back to the original table and drop the "new table". It works also on the standard edition of the SQL Server.

Comment: A quick clarification on step 3 : table isn't partitioned.How do I use SWITCH command.

Comment: You can switch data between two identical tables even if they are not partitioned and even on the standard editions. The difference between partitioned and non-partitioned table is in principle that the non-partitioned table has just one partition (which can be switched). Look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141530/when-you-switch-table-a-to-table-b-does-the-index-data-get-switched-as-well for an example.